# Performance benchmark between boost graph and tigerGraph, Amazon Neptune, etc

Tags: amazon-neptune, boost-graph, tigergraph

This might be a controversial topic, but I am concerned about the performance of boost graph vs commercial software such as TigerGraph, since we need to choose one.
I am inclined to choose Boost, but I am concerned whether performance-wise, boost is good enough.
Disregarding anything around persistence and management, I am concerned with boost graph's core performance of algorithms.

If it is good enough, we can build our application logic on top of it without worry.

Also, I got below benchmarks of LDBC SOCIAL NETWORK BENCHMARK.
[LDBC benchmark](https://ldbcouncil.org/benchmarks/snb/)
seems that TuGraph is the fastest...

Is LDBC's benchmark authoritative in the realm of graph analysis software?

Thank you

Comment: If you're focusing on algorithm performance, you should be looking at the other benchmark: https://ldbcouncil.org/benchmarks/graphalytics/ I suppose. See also https://graphalytics.org/

Comment: I tried the first link, it only shows the test scenarios, the page doesn't give me the actual test results.

Comment: It's a test suite. You can probably find the contest participants, or write your own. There's a reference implementation, if you need. All I'm saying that's a relevant benchmark

Answer (score 1):

I would say that any benchmark request is a controversial topic as they tend to represent a singular workload, which may or may not be representative of your workload.  Additionally, performance is only one of the aspects you should look at as each option is built to target different workloads and offers different features:

Boost is a library, not a database, so anything around persistence and management would fall on the application to manage.

TigerGraph is an analytics platform that is focused on running real-time graph analytics, such as deep link analysis.

Amazon Neptune is a fully managed service focused on highly concurrent transactional graph workloads.

All three have strong capabilities and will perform well when used in the manner intended.  I'd suggest you figure out which option best matches the type of workload you are looking to run, the type of support you need, and the amount of operational work you are willing to onboard to make the choice more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, I will formulate my question more clearly.